# Is namespace in C# is something similar to package in Java

Tags: c#, java, namespaces

Exacly as stated in the subject. I do not understand idea of the namespace. Is that something which should work like package in Java?

Comment: Yes, they are the same concept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're similar but not the same. In particular, names are also used for access control in Java (where the default access makes a member available within the same package). That's not the case in .NET - namespaces don't come into accessibility at all in .NET.

Additionally, the way you import types can differ between C# and Java: in Java you can import individual classes, whereas in C# the common using directive imports a whole namespace. On the other hand, C# using directives can also specify aliases, which Java doesn't support.

Both packages and namespaces *are* ways of grouping related types, so to that extent they're the same... but they differ in the details.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are the same concept except that Namespace is about Logical grouping of classes in C# while in Java Package is about both logical as well as physical grouping of classes.

Comment: They're not the same - see my answer for a difference.

Comment: (And it's not clear what you mean by "physical grouping" either, given that a single jar file can contain classes from many packages.)

Comment: In Java, classes belonging to same packages have to be in the same folder (at-least it used to be) and hence apart from logical grouping, they are physically grouped together also. My answer contained same "concept" not about having exactly same. You are right that in detail, there are differences.

Comment: No, they don't have to be as source - it's up to the classloader how the binary classes are located, of course. The convention is to use the package structure for layout, and the standard compiler supports that, but it's not a language requirement.

Comment: (Actually, I think some IDEs fully enforce the layout. So yes, I see your point - but I think it's worth differentiating between what some environments enforce and what's actually part of the language. The language specification mentions file layout as an *option*, but doesn't require it.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, namespace in C# and package in Java are the same concept.

**Java:**

```
package Project.Providers;
```

**C#:**

```
namespace Project.Providers {

}
```

also the way to import packages are different:

**Java:**

```
import Project.Providers.*;
```

**C#:**

```
using  Project.Providers;
```

Comment: No, they're not the same nag. They're similar but not equivalent.

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant teh same concept. I edited my answer.

Comment: I still disagree. The package concept in Java includes accessibility - the namespace concept in C# doesn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet what do you mean when you say "includes accessibility"

Comment: See my answer for more details - basically there's no such thing as package accessibility in C#.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, I still can't get your point about accessibility. Can you give me some example?

Comment: In Java, if you declare a class as just `class Foo { ... }` it's only available within the same package: the package is part of what determines which types and members are available. That's not the case in C#.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, your right here. Voted your answer up :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes Exactly. In Java you use

```
    Import packagename.*;
```

In .net it is

```
    using namespacename;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but there is a difference. in Java each class in a particular file.But in c# one namespace can contain many other namespaces.And they will compile into one dll or exe file.

Comment: *What*? This is comparing apples to oranges.